# UPDATE SQL table to change timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am using php to display an SQL table. When the user selects a row on the table and then clicks a button, I want it to update the timestamp to the current time and appear on the table displayed on the webpage. The SQL query I am using works, however when I click the button, it doesn't change the values in the database, nor does it change anything displayed in the table either. The code I am using is:

I've tried CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and GetDate();, however neither seems to be what I am looking for.

So if the SignOut value is currently at 00:00, I want it to be updated to the current time.

The button appears in the following table:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo "<tr>"."<td>". $row["StudentNum"]. "</td>". "<td>". $row["Name"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["Location"]."</td>"."<td>". substr($row["HomeTime"],0,-3)."</td>"."<td>".substr($row["SignOut"],11,-10)."</td>"."<td>"."<center>"."</center>"."</td>"."<td>"."</td>"."</tr>";

    }

}
 else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

The script to add the time:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _common;

                $("#table tr").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
   var value=$(this).find('td:first').html(); 
    _common = value;
});


function select(){
    alert(_common);

    <?php
    $signingout = "UPDATE signon SET SignOut=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE StudentNum= '_common'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $signingout);
    ?>
}
       </script>
```

Comment: you can't use php in javascript. use ajax to access separate .php files.

Answer (score 0):

You are **can't** mix together client side code and server side code.

PHP is a server side code and can not be mixed with the javascript.
Javascript is a client side code and only lives in the browser, therefore can't be used to contact the database.

So you need to start with isolating your code. Make a new file on the server that contains the php code and call it with javascript and re-render the side with the new values.